# Script to Organize Desktop into Folders/Directories by Extension

Tags: shell-script, files, scripting

I'd like to organize desktops by running a script that places all of your files into folders by extension. I found some code through googling and the code I found creates a folder with the name of the file and places the file in said folder. I don't want a folder per file name... I want one folder to have all .txt, another for .jpg... etc.  I use OS X.

Here's what I have... any direction would be great, thanks!

```
for file in *.txt
    do
        dir="${file%.txt}"
        mkdir -- "$dir"
        mv -- "$file" "$dir"
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you want is a directory per file type, then you want something more like:

```
mkdir txt || { echo "Can't mkdir txt" ; exit 1 ; }
for file in *.txt ; do
    mv -- "$file" txt/
done
```

Note the failure handling on `mkdir`.  In your code, if there is already a *file* with the name contained in the variable `$dir`, your `mkdir --"$dir"` command will *silently* fail, and then your `mv` command will **overwrite** that file.

---

To handle a bunch of arbitrarily named files—all the files with three-character extensions in the current directory—and put them in directories by file extension, you could use the following code (untested):

```
for file in *.??? ; do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    dir="$(echo "$file" | rev | cut -c-3 | rev)"
    mkdir -p "$dir" || { echo "Couldn't mkdir -p $dir; exiting" ; exit 1 ; }
    mv -- "$file" "$dir"
done
```

**Explanation:**

The pattern `*.???` will match all files *and directories* in the current directory whose name ends in a period (`.`) followed by exactly three characters.

The test `[ -f "$file" ]` returns true only if `$file` is a regular file (not a directory or other more specialized type like a device.)  Otherwise, the `continue` statement will skip the rest of that pass through the `for` loop.

The assignment to the `dir` variable looks fancy but really it's just taking the contents of the `$file` variable, reversing it, extracting the first 3 characters (of the reversed string), then reversing that again, and assigning the result as the value of `$dir`.  In other words it's the last three characters of the filename.

Then, `mkdir -p` will return success if the directory already exists, or will create it if it doesn't (and return success).  If it doesn't return success, you don't want to try to move files into it!  Hence the error handling.

Then, the `mv` command just like normal.

---

**A note about error handling:**

You might see constructs like this:

```
mkdir -p "$dir" || echo "Failed, exiting" && exit 1
```

This is imperfect because the `exit` command is only executed if the `echo` command *succeeds* after the `mkdir` command fails.  What you want instead is to have the `exit` command executed *regardless* of whether the `echo` command succeeds, assuming that `mkdir` failed.  This is why I use the curly braces as above.

Comment: Wow thanks for the tip on error handling! That's something I hadn't thought about.

Comment: Question: Does this script only group extensions with 3 letters? "???"
What about extensions with "????" like .html?

Comment: @JovanHernandez, yes, I designed it to only handle 3-letter extensions, just because I like my code to be fairly explicit.  You could adjust it to handle 4-letter extensions only (by adding a `?` to the glob pattern and fixing the `cut -c-3` command) or handle both 3 and 4 letters by running two separate `for` loops in sequence.  If you want to handle all extensions of any length, use G-Man's answer.  (See my further comments below his answer.)

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a directory per file type,
then you want something more like:

```
for file in *.*[!.]
do
    ext=${file##*.}
    mkdir -p -- "$ext"  &&  mv -- "$file" "$ext"/
done
```

Unlike other operating systems, in Unix, `*.*` means, not all files,
but all files whose names *contain* at least one `.` (dot, a.k.a. period),
thus omitting files with names like `txt`, `todolist` and `oddball`. 
(To confuse matters, shell wildcards exclude files
whose names *begin* with a `.` unless the `dotglob` option is set.) 
`*.*[!.]` (or, equivalently, `*.*[^.]`) further restricts this
to files whose names *contain* at least one `.`
*but do not have `.` as the last character*,
thus omitting files with names like `oddball.` and `odd.ball.`. 
AFAICT, this is a good characterization
of files whose names have a non-null extension.

`ext=${file##*.}` extracts that extension,
by deleting everything up to and including the last dot. 
If the above analysis is correct, this should be non-null. 
The `-p` option causes `mkdir` not to fail if the argument already exists
(and is a directory). 
If you have plain files with names like `txt`, `pdf`, and `jpg`,
and also files with names like `shopping_list.txt`
(which will yield `ext=txt`), or in some other edge cases
(e.g., you don’t have write permission in the current directory,
or there’s no space left in the filesystem),
the `mkdir` *will* fail and will issue its own diagnostic message. 
AND, because of the `&&` (as suggested by @Wildcard),
the following `mv` will not be attempted.

The `/` at the end of the `mv` command is a safety net to prevent the clobbering of plain files with names like `txt`, `pdf`, and `jpg`.

```
    mv -- "$file" "$ext"/
```

will simply fail if the destination name exists as a plain file
(or any file type other than a directory).

Comment: The assignment of `ext` here is simple to look at, but will fail (badly) on some edge cases.  For instance, a filename that ends in a `.` will cause `ext` to be set to a null string, and both `mkdir` and `mv` will fail silently.  (With `mv -- "$file" "$ext"/` it will fail unless you have permission to write to `/`, which you hopefully don't when you run this script.)  (cont'd)

Comment: Also consider odd "extensions" such as a filename `birthday party.todolist`.  If you also have a file called `todolist`, it would be silently overwritten by your `birthday party.todolist`.  Further, if you have a whole bunch of `files.todolist`, *all* of them will disappear except for the last one, which will be renamed as `todolist`.  Always test for error conditions.

Comment: OK, good point about filenames ending with `.`, but what do you mean “`mv` will fail silently”?  A command like `mv oddfile. ""` fails with “mv: cannot move ‘oddfile.’ to ‘’: No such file or directory”.  And I’ve already acknowledged that a plain file called `txt` causes problems.  What does `todolist` add to the discussion?

Comment: Not everything that needs to be done, needs to be done well.  Absolutely, if you’re writing a polished gem of a script to install on your system for future use, and to distribute to other people, it should include error checking.  *This* is the sort of thing that might be a one-off situation.  In such a situation, it might be good enough to run the script interactively and look for the error message(s) from `mkdir` and `mv`.

Comment: Sorry, rather than "fail silently" I should have said "fail without preventing bad stuff".  I do take your meaning about one-off situations—my comments are the sort of info re robustness that I loved to find on this site when I was first learning `bash` scripting.  (Pay it forward.... ;)

Comment: Actually I think the most dramatic improvement that could be made with a simple tweak to your code would be to add `|| continue` to the end of the `mkdir` command (or equivalently, join the `mkdir` and `mv` commands with a `&&`).  That's something I would do even for a one-off use.  (I'm really not trying to be super-critical, just trying to help.)